# How do I run and control more than one Turtlebot in a single simulation gazebo / Ros

Tags: kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found no .cpp file or .h. I've tried every way but can not find how to make a smooth and efficient way to each turtlebot own your odometer.

I have lost months trying to edit the xml / launch in several ways but in the end do not get anywhere. And I see that is a very common question.

Please be clear. If not understood my question is: **How do I run and control more than one Turtlebot in a single simulation gazebo / Ros.**

(Ros hydro)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201639/how-do-i-run-and-control-more-than-one-turtlebot-in-a-single-simulation-gazebo-/-ros./) by [ThiagoHMBezerra](https://answers.ros.org/users/21467/thiagohmbezerra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-01-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure what the real solution is (such that gazebo will directly publish odometry and tf for multiple robots), but I put together a hacky solution which was usable for me. Check out the two launch files in [rosh_turtlebot_demo](https://github.com/dlaz/rosh_turtlebot_demo) for how to startup gazebo and spawn two robots, and [publish_odom.py](https://github.com/dlaz/rosh_turtlebot_demo/blob/master/scripts/publish_odom.py) for publishing odometry and tf.

The key is subscribing to [gazebo/model_states](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/gazebo_msgs/html/msg/ModelState.html) and republishing the odom/tf data.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ThiagoHMBezerra](https://answers.ros.org/users/21467/thiagohmbezerra/) on 2015-01-27**:\

Perfect, really was that I needed. I made some changes to be able to work with my project. Thank you very much.

PS: I will not need it but at some script "r = Rand ()" (I think that's it) is returning error.

**Solved!**